# Disappears tab that shall be visible

Tags: css

Once I click on the title of the menu `a`, the bottom tab is displayed `#sub_backbone` or `#sub_backbone_center` `#sub_backbone_end` depending on the location of the button:
Here's the code:

```
/*After hover link show me the menu*/
div#menu ul li a:hover + #sub_backbone,
div#menu ul li a:hover + #sub_backbone_center,
div#menu ul li a:hover + #sub_backbone_end{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But after I am bringing mouse on the tab `#sub_backbone` ... it disappears but should not disappear, there will be an additional menu. 
Ie when selecting a title, the tab should not disappear when I drive my mouse over it.
How can solve this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It disappears because you are moving away from the `a` link, which causes the styles to revert back to their defaults (I presume that the default style of `#sub_backbone` and others is `opacity: 0`).

The logic is simple: add an additional `:hover` style to `#sub_backbone` and others like this:

```
#sub_backbone:hover {
    opacity: 1
}
```

Remember that this will only work if there is no distance between the `a` and `#sub_backbone` elements.

Edit: here's a jsfiddle with an example: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/LD9mb/4/). I've replaced the `opacity: 1` with `display: block`

Comment: Thank you, everything worked, but now when I turn on the tab, I should display the title menu border as work: hover, but it immediately disappears and shows only the title.

Comment: Could you update your post with an example? Or perhaps post is as a jsfiddle

Comment: This is a problem that I once had to solve. Apparently, I'm not aware of a non-Javascript solution.